# Python GTK+ 3: How to add spinner widget to grid?

Tags: python, gtk3

So basically I'm using a grid full of buttons, and I want to add a Spinner object to that same grid. Kind of like:

```
   self.spinner = Gtk.Spinner()
   self.grid.attach(self.spinner, 0, 1, 1, 1)
```

However when I try to attach the spinner object to the grid, nothing draws other than some extra vertical, blank spacing. What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The spinner is invisible unless you start it with `self.spinner.start()`

Comment: Still doesn't seem draw. I add self.spinner.start()  right after I attach it.